# GitHub Actions Database Migrations Run Successfully but Tables Not Actually Created

Tags: azure, github, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database, github-actions

I have a Blazor Webassembly app that I am deploying to Azure App Service. I am using an Azure SQL Server database. I am trying to set up CI/CD using Github Actions.

```
name: Build and deploy .NET Core application to Web App ForumApp
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ForumAppServer
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: ForumApp\Server\published
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 7.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: ForumApp\Server
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Install .Net Tools
      run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef    
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Update Database
      run: dotnet-ef database update -s ForumApp\Server
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --no-build
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}  
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Deploy to Azure WebApp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.ForumApp_D4E3 }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

The app builds and is published successfully. According to the output from the build and deploy, the database and tables are all created. However, when I view the database tables with SQL Server Management Studio, or Azure Data Studio, the tables are not visible. I don't understand why. Do I need to setup permissions?

When I run the build again, the migration runs again, so it seems like the EF Tools believes the migration needs to be run again as well. Maybe I need to publish artifacts of the migration? What could be the problem?

```
Run dotnet-ef database update -s ForumApp\Server
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (515ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      CREATE DATABASE [ForumDB];
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (159ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') <> 5
      BEGIN
          ALTER DATABASE [ForumDB] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
      END;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (28ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
          [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
          [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
      );

...

more tables created ...

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
      VALUES (N'20230722161736_InitialMigration', N'7.0.9');
Done.
```

[image: SSMS Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out and wanted to post the answer in case someone lands here looking for some help.

Credit to https://dotnetthoughts.net/continuous-database-deployment-with-github-actions/

Basically, you generate the migration as an SQL file and then you execute the SQL statement to perform the database updates. The SQL statement might have CREATE, UPDATE, INSERT, or DROP statements. The SQL file is created automatically by executing

`dotnet ef migrations script --project ForumApp\Server --output ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/sql/sql-script.sql --idempotent --context ApplicationDbContext --no-build`

Here is the full yml file:

```
name: Build and deploy .NET Core application to Web App ForumApp
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ForumApp
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: ForumApp\Server\published
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 7.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: ForumApp\Server
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Install EF Tool
      run: |
          dotnet new tool-manifest
          dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Generate scripts
      run: dotnet ef migrations script --project ForumApp\Server --output ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/sql/sql-script.sql --idempotent --context ApplicationDbContext --no-build
    - name: Azure SQL Deploy
      uses: Azure/sql-action@v1
      with:
        # Name of the Azure SQL Server name, like Fabrikam.database.windows.net.
        server-name: ${{ secrets.DB_SERVER }}
        # The connection string, including authentication information, for the Azure SQL Server database.
        connection-string: ${{ secrets.CONNECTION_STRING }}
        # Path to SQL script file to deploy
        sql-file: ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/sql/sql-script.sql
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --no-build
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}  
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Deploy to Azure WebApp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.ForumApp_D4E3 }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```